# Use of nested ternary expression in .zshrc prompt configuration

Tags: zsh, zshrc, zsh-alias

what is wrong with my RPS1 expression

`RPS1='%(t.[Ding!].%(t30.[Dong!].[%T]))'`

Explanation:

I want to get [Ding!] if it is 11am, [Dong!] if it is 11:30am and if both is not true just normal time like [11:33]. But what is wrong?

Tanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numerical argument to the ternary expression needs to be either just before or just after the opening parenthesis (See [the section on *Conditional Substrings in Prompts*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Conditional-Substrings-in-Prompts) in the ZSH manual) . So either of those will work:

```
RPS1='%(t.[Ding!].%30(t.[Dong!].[%T]))'
RPS1='%(t.[Ding!].%(30t.[Dong!].[%T]))'
```